# Facing nullpointerexception on spark3 while using foreach on dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have the following code snippet where I am trying to access some fields inside foreach. I dont wish to use dataframe apis as its some custom logic i am trying it.

IT works perfectly fine on local but breaks on my databricks cluster. Not sure if its a driver-executor problem, because logic seems straight forward to me

code snippet:

```
dataframe.rdd.foreachPartition(partitions => {
        partitions.foreach(line => {
          try {
            logger.error("Event type is" + line.getAs[String]("event_type"))
          } catch {
            case ex: Exception => {
              logger.error(ex.getMessage, ex)
            }
          }
        })
      })
```

The error I face is :

```
(10.40.20.199 executor 3): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
```

I am using scala 2.12 with spark 3.1.2

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your `partitions` variable has chances to be null.
Can you check it by an `if`, before, to check if it involved?

Comment: I tried using this too, but same results

```dataframe.rdd.foreach(line => {
          try {
            logger.error("Event type is" + line.getAs[String]("event_type"))
          } catch {
            case ex: Exception => {
              logger.error(ex.getMessage, ex)
            }
          }```

Comment: It breaks on ```line.getAs[String]("event_type")```

Comment: With a breakpoint (or a `System.println`) on the statement `logger.error("event type is", + line.getAs[String]("event_type"))`, what are the values of the variables `logger` and `line` before running that statement?

Comment: @mythic are you sure the logger is not null? using logger inside transformation it has to be transient variable.